# Is this query sufficient to checksum a database?

Tags: mysql

I'm using Elasticbeanstalk (and a MySQL RDS) for my client application and an EC2 to act as a utility server to keep all individual client databases up to date. Because Elasticbeanstalk is dodgy when it comes to files unless I'm using an S3 I figured it'd be better to use a database only solution. My goal is to create a checksum of each client database and track a running history of expected checksums to know when it's time to update.

My question is: What is the best way to easily determine that a production schema matches the installed schema in MySQL?

I wrote this query to handle it, but are there any pitfalls doing it this way?

```
SELECT MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(
        COALESCE(TABLE_NAME, ''), 
        COALESCE(COLUMN_NAME, ''),
        COALESCE(ORDINAL_POSITION, ''), 
        COALESCE(COLUMN_DEFAULT, ''), 
        COALESCE(IS_NULLABLE, ''),
        COALESCE(DATA_TYPE, ''), 
        COALESCE(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ''),
        COALESCE(CHARACTER_SET_NAME, ''),
        COALESCE(COLLATION_NAME, ''),
        COALESCE(COLUMN_TYPE, ''),
        COALESCE(COLUMN_KEY, ''))),
    SHA1(GROUP_CONCAT(
        COALESCE(TABLE_NAME, ''), 
        COALESCE(COLUMN_NAME, ''),
        COALESCE(ORDINAL_POSITION, ''), 
        COALESCE(COLUMN_DEFAULT, ''), 
        COALESCE(IS_NULLABLE, ''),
        COALESCE(DATA_TYPE, ''), 
        COALESCE(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ''),
        COALESCE(CHARACTER_SET_NAME, ''),
        COALESCE(COLLATION_NAME, ''),
        COALESCE(COLUMN_TYPE, ''),
        COALESCE(COLUMN_KEY, '')))  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
```